# Windows Batch, how to pause then close window?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Windows batch file, I want the window close itself after user hit a key.

For example

```
@echo off
echo ---------------------
echo  hit a key will close
echo ---------------------
pause
exit /b
```

but it won't close

Comment: `exit` not `exit /b`

Comment: Did you by chance look at the help? `exit /?`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add `echo hit a key will close`; basically the `pause`
command already says that for you.

But if you want to add your own custom message you can add 
`pause>nul`
and add an echo above that for a custom exit message,
then type
`exit`
after the `pause >nul`.

Answer (score 0):

In the RPG I'm working on, I use a quitgame.bat as I also need to close other processes when the batch exits.

CHOICE is the command I use for most input, and I present the option to 'Q'uit at all times (single keypress to exit the game). when the user selects this Choice, the errorlevel check has the Batch go to a label to Call my quitgame.bat

```
Set ask=CHOICE /N /C:
Set then= /M ""
Set do=IF ERRORLEVEL ==

%ask%nqfmie%then%
%do%6 GOTO enterSL
%do%5 GOTO viewinv
%do%4 GOTO market
%do%3 GOTO forcereset
%do%2 GOTO quit
%do%1 GOTO nextpage

:quit
CALL "%Quitgame%"
```

In my quitprogram:

```
@ECHO OFF
```

REM program to taskkill vbs scripts and child processes

```
CALL "%killmusic%"
```

REM deletes all vbs scripts created during programs execution

```
DEL /Q %sounds%\*.vbs
```

REM closes the command console

```
EXIT
```

If you dont have other processes or multiple bat files to warrant calling another program, just use a label you can goto using choice.

```
:quit
Exit
```